# Unable to connect Google Apps Script to Plaid API

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, plaid

What's up team, I'm trying to use Plaid to automatically populate a Google Sheet with financial statements set up in my Plaid account. I've seen this done recently by some companies for a fee (e.g. https://www.budgetsheet.net/). I've also seen it done by developers a couple of years ago (see https://github.com/hirefrank/plaid-txns-google-sheets). This is what I want to do, but the Plaid API has updated since then to remove the public key from usage in place of a Link Token: https://plaid.com/docs/link/link-token-migration-guide/

The workflow is supposed to be as follows:

1. Make a request to create a link token with the client ID and secret.
2. Use the link token to open Link. In the onSuccess callback, send the temporary public_token to your app's server.
3. Make a request to exchange the public_token for a permanent access_token and item_id for the new Item.
4. Store the access_token and use it to make product requests for your user's Item.

I can create the link_token from the following call (the link token is at **responseJSON.link_token**):

```
/************************************************************************************
 * 
 * Creating function to get access token
 * 
 ************************************************************************************/

function getLinkToken(CLIENT_ID, SECRET) {
  
  // Specify headers
  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };

  // Build data for link token
  var data = {
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'secret': SECRET,
    "client_name": "ryanmcslomo",
    "products": ["auth", 'transactions'],
    "language": "en",
    "country_codes": ["US"],
    "user": {
      // "client_user_id": "unique-per-user",
      "client_user_id": "ryanmcslomo",
    },
  };

  // Build params
  var parameters = {
    'headers': headers,
    'payload': JSON.stringify(data),
    'method': 'post',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  };

  // Call link token API with params
  var url = "https://development.plaid.com/link/token/create";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters);
  var responseJSON = JSON.parse(response);

  //Return JSON containing Link Token
  return responseJSON;
}
```

But after that I'm unsure how to initialize the Link with a Link Token (much less grab the Public Token to be exchanged for an Access Token). When I try to pass the link token as the public token to authenticate, it (of course) fails:

```
  // Build data for access token
  var data2 = {
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'secret': SECRET,
    "public_token": responseJSON.link_token
  };

  // Build params
  var parameters2 = {
    'headers': headers,
    'payload': JSON.stringify(data2),
    'method': 'post',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  };

  // Call API with params
  var url2 = "https://development.plaid.com/item/public_token/exchange";
  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, parameters2);
  var response2JSON = JSON.parse(response2);

  // return JSON response with Link Token
  return response2JSON;
}
```

response2JSON:

```
{
display_message: null
documentation_url: "https://plaid.com/docs/?ref=error#invalid-input-errors"
error_code: "INVALID_PUBLIC_TOKEN"
error_message: 'provided token is the wrong type. expected "public", got "link"'
error_type: " INVALID_INPUT"
...
}
```

Any ideas? Not sure how to do this as Google Apps Script. Thank you for your help!

Other places I've looked:

- Stripe integration

  - https://stripe.com/docs/ach?__hstc=20629287.99a265337744294b740e0787aea508c4.1574726400918.1574726400919.1574726400920.1&__hssc=20629287.1.1574726400921&__hsfp=1895241284
- Doing it in React

  - https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/#making-api-requests
- Token docs

  - https://plaid.com/docs/api/tokens/
- SDK on GitHub

  - https://github.com/plaid/plaid-java/issues/105

Comment: When each values for using the request can be supposed as the valid values, I think that your both Google Apps Scripts for requesting are correct. And from the error message, for example, how about confirming whether your `"public_token": responseJSON.link_token` retrieved from your 1st request can be used for using the endpoint of `https://development.plaid.com/item/public_token/exchange`, again? I deeply apologize that I cannot propose the clear solution.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, I am happy you have seen my question! I am a giant fan of yours, I follow your blog and have learned a lot of GAS from your teachings. Thanks for everything you do! Back to the question haha, it looks like the link_token is not the valid input for https://development.plaid.com/item/public_token/exchange. The workflow at Plaid says to use a script like this to "initialize" the Link with the link_token: https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/#how-it-works (CTRL+F "Quickstart Link" to see their node and vanilla javascript example). I am perplexed how to do this in Google Apps Script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your current issue. I apologize for this. For example, when you want to convert Javascript of `Quickstart Link` to Google Apps Script, it seems that the sample script uses the Javascript library. So I think that it is required to analyze the library. How about this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually doing something pretty similar! I found it easiest to just use the quickstart to generate the access_token and pass that into my request within apps script.

Answer (score -1):

Initializing Link with a link token on web:

```
const handler = Plaid.create({
  token: 'GENERATED_LINK_TOKEN',
  onSuccess: (public_token, metadata) => {},
  onLoad: () => {},
  onExit: (err, metadata) => {},
  onEvent: (eventName, metadata) => {},
  receivedRedirectUri: null,
});
```

Triggering the call to /item/public_token/exchange:

```
  onSuccess: (public_token, metadata) => {
    fetch('//yourserver.com/get_access_token', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        public_token: public_token,
        accounts: metadata.accounts,
        institution: metadata.institution,
        link_session_id: metadata.link_session_id,
      },
    });
  }
});
```

Source: https://plaid.com/docs/link/web/